# How many generations is needed to go back to get an ethnicity estimate without a DNA test?

Tags: england, dna, family-tree, ethnicity

I'm a 3rd generation Canadian meaning that my great-grandparents were from Europe and my grandparents are Canadian born.

I haven't completed my family tree yet but from the looks of it most of my ancestors were from England and a few from Romania.

I'm a little uneasy about giving my DNA away but I'd still like to know an estimate of my ancestry. How many generations back could give me this information? On one branch I was able to go back to the 1500s Yorkshire, England.

Comment: The current state of DNA databases produces geography correlations that are only really reliable at the continental level. A DNA test could be relied upon to tell you whether your ancestors were mostly European or not. Any finer detail has entertainment value only: sometimes it's right, sometimes it's not. (In other words, don't expect to get genealogical evidence out of admixture.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't like answering a question with a question but - how do you want to define ethnicity? Go back far enough and we are all, every single one of us, 100% African. Most people tend to refer to baseline their ethnicity a little closer than that! But even if you make an arbitrary choice of a specific, recent generation, the ethnicity might change on the generation before that. In this case, I guess I'm defining "ethnicity" as country of origin.

The DNA approach purports to come up with a quantitative derivation of ethnicity - yet all it actually measures is the similarity of your DNA to the DNA of people from those areas living *today*.

If you look at the percentage DNA that you inherit from various generations, see https://dna-explained.com/2017/06/27/ancestral-dna-percentages-how-much-of-them-is-in-you/ then at only 7 generations back, the *average* DNA that you might inherit from someone on that generation is less than 1% and is probably lost in the statistical noise and undetectable.

So DNA estimates of ethnicity are not going to catch minor contributions. But 7 generations back isn't that far back (5G grandparents, as I recollect) and we are all of us liable to make a fuss about a really interesting 6G-GF (say) - I know that I do!

What I guess that I'm saying is that ethnicity is always relative - it depends on which generation you're looking at, and can alter on the next generation back. There isn't a fixed definition and the methods for measuring via DNA are defeated by statistical reality. Best to keep to the paper trail in my view.